# The directional derivative of a given function $w = f (x, y)$ at point $Po (1, 2) $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, vector-spaces, partial-derivative

The directional derivative of a given function $w = f (x, y)$ at point $Po (1, 2) $in the
direction toward $P1 (2, 3)$ is $2\sqrt2$ and in the direction toward $P2 (1, 0)$ is $(-3)$. What is
the value of$\frac{dw}{ds}$
 at Po in the direction toward the origin?

I don't understand what the question wants and how to solve, but I know that the topic is "Directional Derivative" so it contains partial derivatives and vectors, please tell me some tips and hints, where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

If the function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at x,y, then the directional derivative along a vector $\vec{v}$ can be found using
$$
\nabla_{\vec{v}} f(x,y) = \vec{\nabla} f(x,y) \cdot \vec{v}.
$$
The vectors $\vec{v}$ you can find using the given points. You also know the values of *two* of these directional derivatives. This should allow you to find the components of the vector $\vec{\nabla} f(x,y) = (a,b), \quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R} $.

I hope this helps.